# How to get the selected value in ComboBox and use it for second ComboBox query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, combobox

Here is my Code.

I have several ComboBoxes. I need to get Value from selected in ComboBox and use value in different query. All data I do select from Oracle.

This is my first ComboBox and I need to use VALUE of this ComboBox's option in query of second ComboBox. I mean second ComboBox depends on first select.

How I can get "Value"? I tried to use `onchange="this.form.submit()"` but it refreshes the page and loses my select. Maybe is it possible to do it with Ajax...

```html
<tr>
 <div class="form-group" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;padding:2px;">
 <label>Something:</label><span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
 
  <select class="form-control" input-sm name="example" required>         
           
   <OPTION VALUE="">Choose any</OPTION>
            
   <OPTION VALUE="first">first_name</OPTION>
   <OPTION VALUE="second">second_name</OPTION>
          
   </select>
 </div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new php file and name it "js_post.php".  When we chose any option from first ComboBox, javascript sending Value to "js_post.php" and there code is cheking Value and depends on Value selecting option.

````````````````````````html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]="get_data" && isset($_POST["muracietnov_id1"]) && $_POST["muracietnov_id1"] !="")
{

 if($_POST["muracietnov_id1"]==1)
 {
  
//```````````````````````HERE SHould be your connection to DB````````````````
$select_query= sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);
           
while($result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_query)
{
           
echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$result['DATAID'].'">'.$result['NAME'].'</OPTION>';
          
}

 }
?>
````````````````````````

Here is Javascript and HTML that I used.

```js
$("#muracietnov_id").change(function(){
 var url = 'js_post.php';
 var muracietnov_id=$("#muracietnov_id").val();
 var posting = $.post( url, { 'action': 'get_data','muracietnov_id1': muracietnov_id} );
     posting.done(function( data ) {
      //alert(data);
     $("#muracietnov_id2").html(data); 
     
  }); 
});
```

```html
<tr>
 <div class="form-group" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;padding:2px;">
  <label>Müraciət Növü:</label><span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
   
   <select class="form-control" input-sm name="muracietnov" id="muracietnov_id" required>';          
   
     <OPTION VALUE="">Seçiminizi edin</OPTION>';
     
     <OPTION VALUE="1">Su təchizatı</OPTION>';
     <OPTION VALUE="2">Kanalizasiya</OPTION>';
     </select>';
     </div>
</tr>
   
   
<tr>
 <div class="form-group" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;padding:2px;">
  <label>Müraciət Səbəbi:</label><span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
   <select class="form-control" input-sm id="muracietnov_id2" required>
   </select>
 
 </div>
</tr>
```